# Restore Deleted File from Recycle Bin With Original Folder Structure

Tags: windows

I have moved several files from a sub-folder to recycle bin, but unfortunately, I also destoried the parent folders. For instance, I moved file1 to the recycle bin, but I permentaly deletd both folder2 and folder1:

```
-folder1
|-folder2
 |-file1
```

Now I want to restore them to the original location, but I can't sinlply right click a file and restore it from the recycle bin. The worst thing is I even can't find out the original folder structure from the property of a deleted file (it doesn't show the full path).

How can I fix it?

Comment: Did you try looking at volume shadow copies of the parent folder the subfolder you deleted was in?

Comment: No, I don't think I have configured this

Comment: Check to see if it is on. If it is you might have a copy of the folder with files, subfolders, and subfiles.

Answer (score 0):

If you view the recycle bin in details mode it will show you the original location.
Also, you actually can restore the folder, it will just remake the parent folders.

Comment: Yes, I can only trace the 1 level of the upper folder, but the file I removed was several subfolders deeper